# Producing no output?

Tags: java, eclipse, input, output

I am writing a java code that outputs grades and the average, but every time i run the program in eclipse, there's no output. I don't know if it's a problem with eclipse itself or with my code. when i run the code on other sites, it says that there's a NoSuchElementException error. what am i doing wrong? is there something wrong with the input?

The code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {
  ;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char grade;
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int test1 = scanner.nextInt();
    int test2 = scanner.nextInt();
    int test3 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your score: ");
    int score = scanner.nextInt();

    int average = ((test1 + test2 + test3) / 3);

    if (score >= 90) {
      grade = 'A';
    } else if ((score >= 80) && (score < 90)) {
      grade = 'B';
    } else if ((score >= 70) && (score < 80)) {
      grade = 'C';
    } else if ((score >= 60) && (score < 70)) {
      grade = 'D';
    } else {
      grade = 'F';
    }

    // Display the test scores.
    System.out.println("You received test scores of: ");
    System.out.println("Test 1 - " + test1);
    System.out.println("Test 2 - " + test2);
    System.out.println("Test 3 - " + test3);

    // Display the average test score.
    System.out.println("Average score: " + average);

    // Display the letter grade.
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + grade);

    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

I tried changing scanner to input, and it still didn't work. Later, I attempted to change settings in Eclipse, like the run configuration, so that there would be an input box, but there is still no output whatsoever. the console is completely blank. I definitely think that something is wrong with the scanner, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: There is a _semi-colon_ on line 4.

Comment: Are you providing input into the console?

Comment: Works for me as expected. Are you saving file after work(eclipse needs manual saving)? Are you sure the code you wrote is recompiled and you are not running old version?